# Magento2: Youtube video on product details page autoplay

Tags: video, youtube, product, magento2, playback

I have add a youtube video for a product and its works fine on first time (when we click on the product, video will play automatically), if we reload the page the autoplay is disabled.I think that is a default. Is there anyway to make autoplay works on reload also.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: AFAIK, no. For autoplay it needs user interaction = click, scroll, etc. Search how you can autoplay the video. If you need to autoplay the video *without volume*, then, add `&mute=1` at the end of the url of the YouTube video.

Comment: but the video will play on the first load without interaction.when we try reload ,autoplay is disabled